# What is the best and efficient method to search all connected drives?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I need to search all connected drives (logical as well as physical) for a specific file type (e.g. mp4). I know that I can write a recursive function to do so. But I am looking for a most efficient way as this may be a time and CPU consuming operation.

Comment: It is not a cpu consuming operation, your program is entirely throttled by the speed of the disk drive.  A terabyte takes an easy minute or two.  There are no software tricks to make drives faster, other than indexing.  Expecting files to be stored in a specific location is the normal approach.

Comment: I was not asking about making the drive faster. My question is about the algorithm and approach to scan the drives. For my 250GB hard disk (4 partitions), it took around 7 minutes to finish. However, I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `dir` command for this, and the let the filesystem do what it's good at.

```
static string[] SearchFiles(params string[] patterns)
{
    var searchPatterns = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        .Where(d => d.IsReady && d.DriveType != DriveType.NoRootDirectory)
        .SelectMany(d => patterns.Select(p => d.RootDirectory + p));

    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir " + String.Join(" ", searchPatterns) + " /s/b";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();

        string strOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return strOutput.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray());
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
var files = SearchFiles("*.jpg", "*.mp?", "*.mpeg");
```

Since this operation might take sometime, you could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for running it in a background thread.

Also, since the output might be quite large, you might consider outputing to a file (e.g. by adding `> out.txt` after `/s/b`) and processing the file, instead of returning an array of strings.

**EDIT:**
You could improve performance by searching drives in parallel.

```
static List<string> SearchFiles(params string[] patterns)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    Parallel.ForEach(drives, drive =>
    {
        if (!drive.IsReady || drive.DriveType == DriveType.NoRootDirectory)
            return;

        var searchPatterns = patterns.Select(p => drive.RootDirectory + p);

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir " + String.Join(" ", searchPatterns) + " /s/b";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();

            string strOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            result.AddRange(strOutput.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The method is good. but it does not handle UnauthorizeAccessException. I am getting exceptions in documents folder. Once an exception occurs, it stop working on that drive. I am running it in a console application with administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it work. The code is as below:

```
 static List<string> SearchFiles(string pattern)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (string drive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("searching " + drive);
            var files = FindAccessableFiles(drive, pattern, true);
            Console.WriteLine(files.Count().ToString() + " files found.");
            result.AddRange(files);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<String> FindAccessableFiles(string path, string file_pattern, bool recurse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        var list = new List<string>();
        var required_extension = "mp4";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            yield return path;
            yield break;
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        if (null == file_pattern)
            file_pattern = "*." + required_extension;

        var top_directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        // Enumerate the files just in the top directory.
        IEnumerator<FileInfo> files;
        try
        {
            files = top_directory.EnumerateFiles(file_pattern).GetEnumerator();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            files = null;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            FileInfo file = null;
            try
            {
                if (files != null && files.MoveNext())
                    file = files.Current;
                else
                    break;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                continue;
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException)
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield return file.FullName;
        }

        if (!recurse)
            yield break;

        IEnumerator<DirectoryInfo> dirs;
        try
        {
            dirs = top_directory.EnumerateDirectories("*").GetEnumerator();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dirs = null;
        }


        while (true)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = null;
            try
            {
                if (dirs != null && dirs.MoveNext())
                    dir = dirs.Current;
                else
                    break;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                continue;
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var subpath in FindAccessableFiles(dir.FullName, file_pattern, recurse))
                yield return subpath;
        }
    }
```